# New user and recurring events to distribution lists in outlook

Tags: outlook, office365

We use distribution lists (DL) in our organization for its different groups, and using these DLs we hold weekly meetings, as an Outlook recurring event, to which the appropriate DLs are invited.

Whenever a new person is added to the organization, he is added to the DLs of the groups he will work in.

Is there an easy way to make the new outlook user invited to all the preexisting recurring events of the DLs he joined?

The only solution I see is to contact the event owners to resend their recurring events whenever someone joins the organization, which sounds manual and messy.

Comment: `Is there an easy way to make the new outlook user invited to all the preexisting recurring events of the DLs`. There is no linkage between the DL's and the calendar events. A DL is a multi-valued list of distinguished names located in an attribute in an LDAP directory. The messaging and calendar system is completely separate. You would need to write code to check the DL for new members, and use one or more reference mailbox calendars to add them to calendar events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I have found a similar thread for your reference: [How to automatically invite new people to existing meeting](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-automatically-invite-new-people-to-existing/53e8a1a1-5f8f-4ec2-acd5-30531abc61e7)

In addition, here are some discussions on this issue for your reference as well: [Auto invite new distribution list members to existing meeting notice/calendar entry](https://www.reddit.com/r/Office365/comments/b6p8oo/auto_invite_new_distribution_list_members_to/)

Comment: Do above suggestions work for you? How is your issue going now?